# pip doesn't list older versions of tensorflow

Tags: python, python3, pip, 20.04

I'm trying to install an older version of Tensorflow but the available ones are only the latest three pre-release versions.

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow<2.0.0,>=1.2.0 (from -r /opt/intel/openvino_2020.2.120/deployment_tools/model_optimizer/install_prerequisites/../requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0rc2, 2.2.0rc3)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow<2.0.0,>=1.2.0 (from -r /opt/intel/openvino_2020.2.120/deployment_tools/model_optimizer/install_prerequisites/../requirements.txt (line 1))
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is because apparently Tensorflow doesn't support Python 3.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up installing 3.7 (the latest version compatible with Tensorflow < 2) from the deadsnakes ppa:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa`

Answer (score 2):

welcome to AskUbuntu.

At the repositories of Ubuntu 20.04 you can find other versions of Python, for example, Python 3.6.

```bsh
apt search python3.6
```

When working with Python, it is a good practice to use a Virtual Environment that will isolate the libraries used by your project by the libraries of the system. If you do not install Python libraries on your system, you will avoid the chance to have a library mess on your system. All in all, use Virtual Environments.

For example, the following instructions will create a virtual environment for your project using Python 3.6. If I'm not mistaken, Tensorflow supports Python 3.6:

```
# Install Python 3.6
sudo apt install -y python3.6 python3.6-venv

# If you do not have a folder for your project, just create one
mkdir folder-for-my-project && cd folder-for-my-project

# Create the virtual environment
python3.6 -m venv venv

# Activate the virtual environment
source ./venv/bin/activate

# At this point, every python program and command that your run will use the
# python interpreter of your virtual environment
python -V

# Update pip
pip install --update pip

# Install tensorflow and other libraries required by your project
pip install tensorflow pytest flake8
```

Remember to activate your virtual environment from the command line if you want to use the Python3.6 interpreter of your project. Tools like PyCharm will detect and make use of the interpreter of your project.

For more details on virtual environments, check the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)